# Spring boot and drools integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, drools

I'm trying to run drools 6.2.0.Final with Spring Boot 1.2.2.RELEASE. I configured drools as the documentation says. My kie-context.xml configuration file is where I keep the drools beans and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:kie="http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                      http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring.xsd">

<kie:kmodule id="sample_module">
    <kie:kbase name="kbase1" packages="composition-rules">
        <kie:ksession name="ksession1" type="stateless"/>
    </kie:kbase>
</kie:kmodule>

<bean id="kiePostProcessor" class="org.kie.spring.KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor"/>
```

as i try to compile the application and run with spring-boot i get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6ab6cc3b: startup date [Wed Apr 15 13:57:02 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:357)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:150)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:836)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:342)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
at skeleton.StorfinoApplication.main(StorfinoApplication.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get all ZipFile entries: /home/lukasz/dev/skeleton/application/target/application-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!
at org.drools.core.util.IoUtils.indexZipFile(IoUtils.java:133)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ZipKieModule.<init>(ZipKieModule.java:20)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.createInternalKieModule(ClasspathKieProject.java:186)
at org.kie.spring.KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor.createKieModule(KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor.java:189)
at org.kie.spring.KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor.addKieModuleToRepo(KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor.java:162)
at org.kie.spring.KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor.java:121)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:177)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
at skeleton.StorfinoApplication.main(StorfinoApplication.java:23)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/user-name/dev/skeleton/application/target/application-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar! (No such file or directory)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)
at org.drools.core.util.IoUtils.indexZipFile(IoUtils.java:124)
... 21 more
```

The command I used for building  the project is:
`mvn clean package` and i run it as a jar file (`java -jar application/target/application-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`).

A thing that caught my attention is that the file path (the one which is not found) has an exclamation mark at the end (it is not supposed to be here). The other thing that i observed is that when i run the project in IntelijIdea ide it succeeds to build and works properly.

What could be the reason of such error?

Comment: I have sometimes seen such "paths" when they tried to reference files inside JAR/WAR file but there was usually second part afterwards e.g. `app.jar!path/to/file.xml`. The difference between JAR and InteliJ is that there your "class files" are no inside the jar. Best would be to debug KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor

Comment: Yes ... it will be due to Spring Boot producing a 'fat' jar. Containing dependencies. I seem to remember hearing elsewhere, of bugs relating to Drools 6 classpath scanning. Possibly just relating to `kie-spring`, because I personally don't use it, and have Spring Boot projects without such issues. For example: https://github.com/gratiartis/buspass-ws

Comment: You are probably right. I tried to use kie-camel (which depends on kie-spring) and after further investigation i see that it tries to read something like this from the classpath: `jar:file:/home/lukasz/dev/skeleton/application/target/application.jar!/ ` (yes - nothing after the exclamation mark). It all happens in the KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor as the logs said earlier. 

Do you think I could work it around by deploying it not as a fat jar (war or some other options)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried the same and ended up building an [spring-boot-starter-drools](https://github.com/jonashackt/spring-boot-starter-drools) for that, because there was nothing working for me out there. I didn´t use the XML-Configuration, because the latest Spring configuration is all about doing with Java only - i would also recommend that in your case.

**Suggestions:**

1. Just use the starter, as decribed in the starter or in the [example project](https://github.com/jonashackt/springdrools)
2. Integrating Drools into your Spring Boot-Project with this working configuration:

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class DroolsAutoConfiguration {

   private static final String RULES_PATH = "rules/";

   @Bean
   public KieFileSystem kieFileSystem() throws IOException {
       KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = getKieServices().newKieFileSystem();
       for (Resource file : getRuleFiles()) {
           kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(RULES_PATH + file.getFilename(), "UTF-8"));
       }        
       return kieFileSystem;
   }

   private Resource[] getRuleFiles() throws IOException {
       ResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
       return resourcePatternResolver.getResources("classpath*:" + RULES_PATH + "**/*.*");
   }

   @Bean
   public KieContainer kieContainer() throws IOException {
       final KieRepository kieRepository = getKieServices().getRepository();

       kieRepository.addKieModule(new KieModule() {
           public ReleaseId getReleaseId() {
               return kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId();
           }
       });

       KieBuilder kieBuilder = getKieServices().newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem()); 
       kieBuilder.buildAll();

       return getKieServices().newKieContainer(kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId());
   }

   private KieServices getKieServices() {
       return KieServices.Factory.get();
   }

   @Bean
   public KieBase kieBase() throws IOException {
       return kieContainer().getKieBase();
   }

   @Bean
   public KieSession kieSession() throws IOException {
       return kieContainer().newKieSession();
   }

   @Bean
   public KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor kiePostProcessor() {
       return new KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor();
   }
   }
   ```
3. There are conflicts of spring-versions, because Spring Boot is based upon Spring 4.x and kie-spring depends on Spring 3.2 - i got the silliest Exceptions, till in the end I excluded all the 3.2-dependecies in my pom.xml:

   ```
   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
   <artifactId>kie-spring</artifactId>
   <version>${drools.version}</version>
   <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
       <exclusion>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
       <exclusion>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
       <exclusion>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   ```